# Merging item in two lists with a separator

Tags: python-3.5

I have two separate lists, "a" and "b". I'm trying to merge them together so it shows the items in the two lists with a hyphen in between.

I tried to using the zip and join functions but I wasn't able to solve the issue.

```py
a = ['USA', 'Australia', 'Netherlands', 'Sweden', 'France', 'Spain']
b = ['Washington', 'Canberra', 'Amsterdam', 'Stockholm', 'Paris', 'Barcelona']
##I tried using zip 
c = CT = zip(a,b)
##I got: 
[('USA', 'Washington'),
 ('Australia', 'Canberra'),
 ('Netherlands', 'Amsterdam'),
 ('Sweden', 'Stockholm'),
 ('France', 'Paris'),
 ('Spain', 'Barcelona')] 
Tried to use join as well, but that didn't work



Ideally, the output should be:
USA-Washington
Australia-Canberra
Netherlands-Amesterdam
Sweden-Stockholm
France-Paris
Spain-Barcelona

Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a list comprehension over the zipped items:

```
[x + '-' + y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `join` to each result of `zip`.

```py
c = ['-'.join(x) for x in zip(a, b)]
```

Or you can use a for loop.

```py
c = []
for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
    c.append('{}-{}'.format(a[i], b[i]))
```